# Windows 10 - unclean power off constantly corrupting installation

Tags: boot, windows-10, laptop

I have a new Asus K501UB laptop that had Windows 10 installed, and I've been having a lot of issues relating to installation corruption. Due to this, plus the bloatware that comes installed, I installed my own fresh copy of Windows 10, and I'm still experiencing the issues. The issue is that whenever the machine is powered off 'uncleanly' (i.e. the battery dies, or the power button is held down), 99% of the time the Windows 10 installation will corrupt - i.e. the laptop gets into a reboot cycle, and then presents me with the startup repair options (Startup repair, refresh, reinstall, system restore) and none of these options ever work.

The only fix I have is to reinstall Windows 10 completely, which I obviously don't want to keep doing! I know uncleanly turning off the laptop isn't the best thing to do, but this never happened with any of my other machines in the past.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Perhaps it's some sort of setting in Windows 10 somewhere? I don't know for sure Windows 10 is the issue, but I can't imagine it's the hardware.

Comment: yes, can confirm, but only some very tiny settings like my task manager settings (view logical cores)

Comment: Does the bad shutdown happen while in safe mode?

Comment: This sounds like maybe write-caching is enabled: if the computer powers down before flushing the cache, you lose data. If the write-cache contains hive(registry) writes etc. you get a bad OS.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to query the S.M.A.R.T. data about your storage device to see if it is having issues.

Open a Command Prompt (Hold Windows key and press R, then type "cmd" in the Run dialog and press enter), then enter these two commands:

```
wmic

diskdrive get status
```

If you do not get a "OK" result then your storage medium may be failing.

Comment: I got the OK result, and I've also used some other applications to query the SMART data and all seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there as a thought - Is this on SSD or Hard drive? Hard drive, you have a better chance. SSD's tend to be touchy little things, corrupt one and you're screwed. Anyways, try this:

Make up a USB bootable copy of Win 10 and boot off ***it*** whenever you run into this problem. You could then tell it to scan the drive for errors. (Yes, I know, sometimes you can't stop it from booting... :-) I get it. But TRY. Reassign the boot to only the USB stick in the BIOS, so it can't find the normal boot drive. That sometimes does the trick).

Then run a **Command Prompt, chkdsk c: /f /r** (or D: or whatever the NORMAL drive letter is assigned, don't scan the USB boot which ~usually~ is X:). Do the /r even though it takes much longer, at least the first time you run into this, later you can do just /f which is much faster. The /r finds bad blocks and marks them out, something that doesn't show well in the SMART data.

You would want to do this BEFORE you let it boot up normally after a crash.

You sound savvy, and this may all seem stupid, but I've found Win 10 (and 8, 8.1 as well) does the new style drive scan but it doesn't seem to work a lot of times, while the old tried & true chkdsk does. Typical MS "fixing" something that wasn't broken and bollixing it up! The trick here is catching it before it boots by itself, and forcing a boot from USB, or even a CD, then running chkdsk.

Worth a try... sure less time than a reinstall, eh?
Oh -
One other thing you could try, (especially on a hard disk) is get a copy of GRC's SpinRite 6 and run at least level 3. It finds and fixes errors Windows will not even see. It's not cheap, but then neither is your time or the psych help you need after this sort of problem! LOL! Great tool to have in your toolbox if you have multiple machines. Works on SSD and Flash drives, but not as well. DON'T use above level 2 on Flash or SSD!!!!

Best of luck! BTW - Don't normally have time to hangout here, just saw the Q and wanted to offer a thought, so little likelihood of followup. Sorry... :-}
PuterPro